# how can I find all Customers who have ordered all articles

Tags: sql, oracle

My Model looks like this:

[image]

and I want to find  all Customers who have ordered all articles.

I have no idea how can I do that! I tried it like this but didn't help:

```
 select distinct k.knr 
 from kunde_tab k 
 where ref(k) in (
                 select ref(k) 
                 from bestellung_tab b,
                      bestelldetails_tab bd 
                 where bd.bestellung=ref(b) 
                   and bd.artikel in (select ref(ar) from artikel_tab ar)
                 );
```

for Translation :

```
Kunde = Customer
Auftrag = Order
Teil= Articel
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell which way your referencing goes, but if you have tables something like:

**Customer** [id, name]

**Order** [id, customerId, orderName, articleId]

**Article**[id, articleName]

You can then do a join:

```
select * from customer
join order on customerId = customer.id
join article on articleId = article.id
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested:** 
I'm having trouble understanding the realtionships on the tables.
I'm assuming

1. kunde.knr is on auftrag as knr
2. teail.nr is on auftrag as nr

So:  First I generate an inline view z to simply returns the count of all articles

We join teil to auftrag as a left join to esnure all articles are listed and to get all the customers having ordered the articles.  (in part or in full)

By using a having clause we ensure the distinct count of articles they ordered match the count of all articles.

```
SELECT O.KNR, count(Distinct O.NR)
FROM  teil A
LEFT JOIN  Auftrag O
 on A.NR = O.NR
CROSS JOIN (Select count(distinct NR) cnt  from teil) z --always returns 1 record
GROUP BY O.KNR
HAVING count(Distinct o.nr) = z.cnt
```

**So logically:**

Get a DISTINCT! count of all the articles ordered by customer.
compare that count to the count of all the articles.  If they match, return the customer, if not, return nothing for the customer.

Comment: thank you ill try it and will tell if its works or not

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
select k.KNr, a.ANr
from Kunde k
inner join Auftrag a
    on k.KNr = a.KNr
cross apply
(select distinct Nr from Teil) t
where t.Nr = a.Nr
group by KNr
having count(a.KNr) = (select count(distinct Nr) ctn from Teil)
```

Comment: If there's no PK-FK relationship constraints in those tables, I suggest you add them.

Comment: This is an Objectoriented Aproach of Database instead of PK-FK we use Object references

Comment: primary key sure but foreign keys we dont need it when we have the Object reference

Comment: i see. those are reference pointers in the diagram. you can try applying the logical flow of the query and use references instead?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Here is the Solution for this :

```
WITH CTE AS
(
 select ac.am, count(ac.am) as cou 
   from ( select k.knr as am ,t.refteil.bezeichnung,  
   count(t.refteil.teilenummer) from kunden k,table(k.auftraege) auf,
   table(auf.positionen) t 
   group by t.refteil.bezeichnung,k.knr) ac 
 group by ac.am 
)
select am from (select * from  cte) 
  where cou =(select count(t.teilenummer) as coun 
  from Teile t);
```